# pip install ngrok ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output

Tags: ngrok

im trying to pip install ngrok but i got the error.
i use ubuntu server
I haven't been able to solve it for hours :(
please help me

```
pip install ngrok
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py:122: PkgResourcesDeprecationWarning: 0.1.36ubuntu1 is an invalid version and will not be supported in a future release
  warnings.warn(
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py:122: PkgResourcesDeprecationWarning: 0.23ubuntu1 is an invalid version and will not be supported in a future release
  warnings.warn(
Collecting ngrok
  Using cached ngrok-0.1.6.tar.gz (3.5 kB)
Collecting ping
  Using cached ping-0.2.tar.gz (10 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python3 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-qanhr0lu/ping/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-qanhr0lu/ping/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-install-qanhr0lu/ping/pip-egg-info
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-qanhr0lu/ping/
    Complete output (8 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-qanhr0lu/ping/setup.py", line 23, in <module>
        from ping import __version__
      File "/tmp/pip-install-qanhr0lu/ping/ping.py", line 196
        except socket.error, (errno, msg):
                           ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure which python ngrok library you are trying to install, but I suspect it's probably pyngrok which is installed using: `pip install pyngrok`

source: https://pyngrok.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

Comment: I don't know what the problem is, but I solved it with using snap.
Thanks for your help :)